# Updating or Deleting a SubDocument using Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Here is my Code which I am using to update a Product from an Array of Nested Documents.
It's works fine but I think I am not doing it in better way. Is there any other way to update it

```
async updateProduct(parent: any, args: any, context: any) {
            const { category_id, product } = args;
    
            const category = await this.categoryService.findById( category_id );
           
            const idx = category.products.findIndex( _product => _product._id.toString() ===  product._id );
    
            if( idx >= 0 ) {
                delete product._id;
                const p = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( category.products[ idx ] ));
                category.products[ idx ] = { ...p, ...product};
                
                return category.save();
            }
    
            throw new NotFoundException('Product Not found');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner way to do so:

```js
await this.categoryService.update({
  _id: category_id
}, {
  $pull: {
    products: product._id
  }
})
```

Or if you want to return the object after update, you can use `findOneAndUpdate` with `{new: true}` optiomn.

The `$pull` operator delete an element from an array.

**UPDATE**

If you want to update a nested document you can use `$arrayFilter`.

For example if you want to update a specific product name. I suppose that you have your specific `product_id`.

```js
await this.categoryService.update({
  _id: category_id
}, {
  $set: {
    'products.$[elem].name': newProductName
  }
}, {
  arrayFilters: [{'elem._id': product_id}]
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. How to update a nested document? For example if I want to change only one property out of many?

Comment: I will update my answer. You can use `$arrayFilters`.